# sudo apt-get purge smbd removed vital pakages

Tags: linux, dependencies, apt, samba, debian-buster

I ran `sudo apt-get purge smbd` after samba decided to beak.
Than it preceded to remove python gnome and many other packages which brought me into a dependency loop.Why did it remove these packages.

here is the part of the [apt log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BsiYe54JKI4_246XZrV6au7pJaacx8ps9KFzpVx4hC0)

Comment: to re install all the removed it copied every thing after today to err.txt and ran this ```grep "Removing" err.txt | awk '{printf("sudo apt-get install --reinstall  %s \n",$2)}' | bash```